# A dumb axiom of collection

Tags: set-theory, logic, axioms

Add to $ZFC$ the following axiom:

> **Dumb Collection**. For any predicate $\phi$ such that there exists a set $y$ satisfying $\phi$, there exists a nonempty set $x$ whose members are precisely the sets $y$ satisfying $\phi$ which don’t contain $x$ as a member or subset. $$\forall\phi\Big(\exists y\big(\phi(y)\big)\implies\exists x\big(x\neq\emptyset\wedge\forall z(z\in x\iff\phi(z)\wedge x\notin z\wedge x\nsubseteq z)\big)\Big).$$ Denote the set guaranteed by this axiom and a predicate $\phi$ by $x_\phi$.

This avoids Russel’s paradox since we now have that $x_{y\notin y}\notin x_{y\notin y}$ by definition, but it isn’t clear that we don’t still have other paradoxes present. If this axiom is consistent,

> What is the consistency strength of $ZFC+$dumb collection?

Comment: For any nonempty $x$, ZFC proves that there is a proper class of sets that do not contain $x$ as an element or subset. Thus the new version is inconsistent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I don’t doubt that you’re correct, I’m just trying to understand what you mean; what is a proper class in ZFC?

Comment: The same as usual: a definable collection of sets that does not form a set.

Comment: As a nit, presumably most classes are not definable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\phi$ to be "$y$ is a singleton", then $x$ is now the set of *all* singletons, except $\{x\}$ itself.

But that's impossible, since then $\bigcup(x\cup\{\{x\}\})$ is the set of all sets.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.

Comment: (in hindsight I should have posted this to MSE, thank you for humoring me anyway)

Comment: (I agree with that sentiment.)

Comment: Your powers are humbling indeed; thank you!